# My Discord bot's mention help command is not working. Can someone help out? (Discord.js, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When my bot is mentioned, I want it to execute a particular command.
However, when it is mentioned, it throws an error which I will paste below, after my code.

P.S: I use a command handler.
P.S 2: This bot is hosted on repl.it

**My index.js code:**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const hosting = require('./hosting.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = process.env.botToken;
const {prefix} = require('./config.json');

module.exports = client

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./commands');

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
}




const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));


for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
  client.user.setPresence({activity: {name: '!1help', type: 'LISTENING'}, status: 'idle'});
  console.log("Bot is running.");
  console.log(client.user.username);
});

const escapeRegex = str => str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');

client.on('message', message => {

const prefixRegex = new RegExp(`^(<@!?${client.user.id}>|${escapeRegex(prefix)})\\s*`);
if (!prefixRegex.test(message.content)) return;

const [, matchedPrefix] = message.content.match(prefixRegex);
  
const args = message.content.slice(matchedPrefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();




if (message.content === "<@833376214609690674>" || message.content === "<@!833376214609690674>") {
  const mCommand = client.commands.get('help')
  mCommand.execute()
}

if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;

const command = client.commands.get(commandName);

try {
    command.execute(message, args);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    message.reply('There was an error trying to execute that command.');
}
})

client.login(token);
```

**My help.js code (This is the command that I want my bot to execute when it is mentioned):**

```
const { prefix } = require('../../config.json');
module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
  category: "utility",
    description: 'Lists all available commands or info about a specific command.',
    usage: '[command name]',
    execute(message, args) {

const data = [];
const { commands } = message.client

if (!args.length) {
  data.push("Here's a list of all my commands:");
data.push(commands.map(command => command.name).join(', '));
data.push("\nYou can use `{prefix}help [command name]` to get info on a specific command!");

return message.author.send(data, { split: true })
    .then(() => {
        if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
        message.reply("I've sent you a DM with all my commands!");
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(`Could not send help DM to ${message.author.tag}.\n`, error);
        message.reply("It seems like I can't DM you! Do you have DMs disabled? If so, please enable them.");
    });
}
const name = args[0].toLowerCase();
const command = commands.get(name) || commands.find(c => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(name));

if (!command) {
    return message.reply("That's not a valid command!");
}

data.push(`**Name:** ${command.name}`);

if (command.aliases) data.push(`**Aliases:** ${command.aliases.join(', ')}`);
if (command.category) data.push(`**category:** ${command.category}`)
if (command.description) data.push(`**Description:** ${command.description}`);
if (command.usage) data.push(`**Usage:** ${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}`);

if (command.cooldown === undefined) {
  data.push(`**Cooldown:** 0 seconds`)
}
else if (command.cooldown === 1) {
  data.push(`**Cooldown:** ${command.cooldown} second`)
}
else {
  data.push(`**Cooldown:** ${command.cooldown} seconds`)
}

message.channel.send(data, { split: true });
},
};
```

**Path to help.js file:**

```
./commands/utility/help.js
```

**Error I recieved in console when bot is mentioned on Discord:**

```
node v12.16.1
/home/runner/MultiBot/commands/utility/help.js:10
const { commands } = message.client
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
    at Object.execute (/home/runner/MultiBot/commands/utility/help.js:10:30)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/MultiBot/index.js:60:12)
    at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/MultiBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/MultiBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/MultiBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/MultiBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/MultiBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/MultiBot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
execute(message, args) {
```

I needed to pass in execute and args this way in the if function in index.js:

```
if (message.content === "<@833376214609690674>" || message.content === "<@!833376214609690674>") {
  const mCommand = client.commands.get('help')
  mCommand.execute(**message, args**)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare your command handler and your own code to activate on mention

your mention function

`mCommand.execute()`

the original command handler

`command.execute(message, args);`

As you see the difference between these two is your pass `message, args` in the command handler function but not in `mCommand.execute()`

as your have no parameters passed you cant get anything from the function in `help.js`

But your trying to access them  `execute(message, args) {`

and as nothing is passed `message` is undefined (args is also undefined)

Simple fix would be below

`mCommand.execute()` => `mCommand.execute(message, args)`

p.s: your should learn javascript, its gonna help your in future

Comment: Lmao, nice your figured out it on your own, i was writing my answer when you were writing it  and posting it :)

Comment: Actually, I didn't figure it out on my own, people from the Discord API discord server helped me out. :)

Comment: Ye saw you asked in d.js ; )